# Unable to click checkboxes after styling

Tags: css

I have tried to style some checkboxes but now I can't click on/ activate/ check them. Radio buttons that are mostly styled the same way do work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $selection = $('.sc-checkbox');

 $selection.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $id = $this.attr('id');

  $this.after( '<label for="' + $id + '"></label>' );
 });
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"].sc-checkbox {
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -102%;
    position: absolute
}
input[type="checkbox"].sc-checkbox+label{
  padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
}
input[type="checkbox"].sc-checkbox+label:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background: transparent;
    border: .14286rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    width: .92857rem;
    height: .92857rem;
    border-radius: .14286rem;
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 0;
    line-height: .92857rem;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
}

input[type="checkbox"].sc-checkbox:checked+label:before {
    background: #3f51b5;
    border: .14286rem solid #3f51b5;
    content: '\E5CA';
    color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<input type="checkbox" class="sc-checkbox" id="test"></label><label for="test">Test</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="sc-checkbox" id="test1" checked></label><label for="test1">Test1</label>
```

When you run the example everything works but on my website it doesn't work.
I have fiddled around with positions, paddings and margins on the `:before` but nothing seems to be working.

I hope someone can help me make the checkboxes work again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the last two lines of your HTML, you end a `</label>` tag without ever opening one, and then open a `<label>` tag just to later close it. Is the first `</label>` accidental?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the jQuery CDN link on your website.

Comment: @Xetnus Yes the first </label> is an accident

Comment: @Michael_B I have jQuery it's just in vendor.min.js

Comment: This site can’t be reached?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 You should be able to. But removed the link since the question was answered. The answer provides the problem code and I don't want to make "ads" to my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a code that fixes a bug when text field isn't selected when label is clicked:

textfields.js, line 30:

```
// Fix bug that text field isn't selected when label is clicked
$('label').click(function() {
    var $id = $(this).attr('for');
    $('#'+$id).trigger('click');
});
```

However this code cause your `click` on the label to be triggered twice, so you get two clicks on the checkbox (which causes your checkbox to  be checked and then unchecked immediately, or the opposite).

I'm not sure if you really need this code or not, but you can change your fix-bug to something like this:

```
// Fix bug that text field isn't selected when label is clicked
$('label').click(function() {
    var $id = $(this).attr('for');
    if ($('#'+$id).is(':checkbox')) {
        return;
    }
    $('#'+$id).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I need that piece of code because for some reason when the label or input was clicked of a textfield the text field wasn't always selected. That piece of code fixed. I wonder how you found that bug, did you dig trough the code on github?

Comment: It indeed was a bit tricky to find it :) I looked at the `label` to see if there are any events that were attacked to it, and I notices there was a `keyup` event attached there. Then I looked through your js files to see which file caused the attach of that specific event, and then it took some debugging time o see what happen when you click on the `label`.